# Как интегрировать отправку OTP с Celery в проект?

Tags: python, django, rest, celery

Вот мой viewset и serialsers. Я хочу интегрировать отправку OTP во время авторизации пользователя. Чтобы пройти успешную авторизацию, нужно ввести 6-ти значный OTP код. Как мне лучше это сделать? Также хочу подключить Celery для отправки OTP кодов.

```
from djoser.views import UserViewSet

class AccountViewSet(UserViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    search_fields = ('^username', '^email', '^first_name', '^last_name')
```

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as UserCreate
from djoser.serializers import UserSerializer


class CustomUserCreateSerializer(UserCreate):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=MAX_LENGTH_PASSWORD,
        required=True,
        write_only=True,
        validators=[
            MinLengthValidator(
                limit_value=MIN_LENGTH_PASSWORD,
                message='Password must be longer than 6 characters'
            ),
            MaxLengthValidator(
                limit_value=MAX_LENGTH_PASSWORD,
                message='Password must be shorter than 30 characters'
            ),
            validate_password
        ],
        help_text=(
            'Enter password.'
            'It must include lowercase and uppercase letters '
            'of the Latin alphabet and numbers.'
        ),
    )
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        validators=[
            UniqueValidator(
                message='This email is already taken',
                queryset=User.objects.all()
            ),
            MaxLengthValidator(
                limit_value=MAX_LENGTH_EMAIL,
                message=(
                    'Email must be shorter than'
                    f'{MAX_LENGTH_EMAIL} characters'
                )
            )
        ],
        required=True
    )
    username = serializers.CharField(
        validators=[
            UniqueValidator(
                message='This username is already taken',
                queryset=User.objects.all()
            ),
            validate_username
        ],
        required=True
    )
    first_name = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=MAX_LENGTH_USERNAME,
        help_text='Enter your first name',
        validators=[validate_first_name],
        required=True
    )
    last_name = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=MAX_LENGTH_USERNAME,
        help_text='Enter your last name',
        validators=[validate_last_name],
        required=True
    )

    class Meta(UserCreate.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id', 'email', 'first_name',
            'last_name', 'username', 'password'
        )


class CustomUserSerializer(UserSerializer):
    class Meta(UserSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id', 'email', 'first_name',
            'last_name', 'username'
        )
```

```
DJOSER = {
       'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
       'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
       'HIDE_USERS': False,
       'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
       'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'users/set_password/{uid}/{token}',
       'SERIALIZERS': {
           'user_create':
               'api.users.users_serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
           'user':
               'api.users.users_serializers.CustomUserSerializer',
           'user_delete':
               'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
           'current_user':
               'api.users.users_serializers.CustomUserSerializer',
           'set_password':
               'djoser.serializers.SetPasswordSerializer',
           'set_password_retype':
               'djoser.serializers.SetPasswordRetypeSerializer',
           'token': 'djoser.serializers.TokenSerializer',
           'token_create': 'djoser.serializers.TokenCreateSerializer',
       },
       'PERMISSIONS': {
           'user': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
           'user_list': ('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),
       },
   }
```

Comment: 1) Отправку куда? / 2) Почему вы хотите именно отправку? Чем не угодили многочисленные приложения-аутентификаторы с поддержкой TOTP?

Comment: 1) Отправку на email пользователя. Достаточны вывести письмо в консоль с кодом
2) Хочу сделать именно через OTP и Celery.